# ListView is full ,But It gives a Null Pointer Exception While trying to change Backround Color

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a list view which is made from strings. There are two items in it.

```
// System.out.println("X->"+listView.getLastVisiblePosition()+"Y->"+listView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
listView.getChildAt(listView.getLastVisiblePosition()).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

When I print the Last and First Visible Position It prints 1 and 0 ;however, It gives an null pointer expectation error , when I try to change background color . What could be the reason?

***The Error-> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference***

It is not necessary ,but I would like to share the implementation of listView as well,

```
      listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewProductList);

    if(products!=null){
        ArrayList<String> names=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<products.size();i++){
            names.add("Ürün Adı-> "+products.get(i).getProductName()+"\n"+"Konum-> "+ products.get(i).getLocationName());
        }

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, names);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the index of the arraylist not of the listview .
something like this :

`int lastIndex = products.indexOf(products.get(products.size() - 1 )) ;`

`int firstIndex = products.indexOf(products.get(0 )) ;`

but you should *ensure that your list is neither empty nor null*.

`listView.getChildAt(lastIndex).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);`

Or

`listView.getChildAt(firstIndex).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);`

Comment: It does not work :()